# Skip invalid dates while showing report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table `@tbl_dates` where I am getting dates for each calname and a column isvaliday defines if a particular row is valid and should be considered as a valid day or not. I wanted to generate a report on the basis of `@tbl_dates` that will show validates and previous valid date for each valid record only. If one date is not a valid date then it should be skipped and previous date must be shown. Please see the output.

```
    declare @tbl_dates table (calname varchar(20), rundate date, isvalidday bit)

    insert into @tbl_dates 
    values('ipc1', '2020-01-01',1),
    ('ipc1', '2020-01-02',1),
    ('ipc1', '2020-01-03',0),
    ('ipc1', '2020-01-04',1),
    ('ipc2', '2020-01-01',0),
    ('ipc2', '2020-01-02',1),
    ('ipc2', '2020-01-03',1),
    ('ipc2', '2020-01-04',1)
```

**Output**

```
     calname    validdate    prevvaliddate 

     ipc1      2020-01-01     NUll 
     ipc1      2020-01-02    2020-01-01
     ipc1      2020-01-04    2020-01-02
     ipc2      2020-01-02     NUll 
     ipc2      2020-01-03    2020-01-02
     ipc2      2020-01-04    2020-01-03
```

Comment: What happened to `'ipc2'` in your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming** that the data should be `'ipc2'` for the latter data, seems like you just need to use `LAG`:

```
SELECT td.calname,
       td.rundate AS validdate,
       LAG(td.rundate) OVER (PARTITION BY td.calname ORDER BY td.rundate) AS prevvaliddate
FROM @tbl_dates td
WHERE td.isvalidday = 1;
```